# Finding matches within lists of lists in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find if there is at least one similar item within all lists inside a Pandas dataframe row.

I have a table with columns 'store' and 'items'. Column'store' contains the list of lists with store ids, and the 'items' column represents the number of product items. I need to check whether all of these products are available in one store or at least in two of them.

I need to create the column 'flag' in which I check whether all of these lists in column 'store' contain at least one same value.

If they do, the flag will be 1.

If they don't, the flag will be 0.

For example, in the first row, all of the products are available in one store - 7, so the flag 1.

In the second row there are no matching values, so the flag will be 0.
In the third row in list1 and list2 there is one common value - 92, but list3 lacks value 92, so the flag will be 0.

| Store | Items | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `[[7], [7], [7, 14], [7, 14]]` | 4 | 1 |
| `[[67, 124], [30, 35, 38]]` | 2 | 0 |
| `[[92, 147], [92], [53]]` | 3 | 0 |

I've wrote this function, but it doest work even for the first case

```
   def same_store(row):
        if row['items'] == 1:
            return 1
        elif row['items'] > 1:
            for list in row['store']:
                if any(x in list for x in row['store']):
                    return 1
                else:
                    return 0
```

Comment: Yet, `14` is not in all stores for the first row, can you clarify? Are the numbers in the list store ids or product ids?

Comment: I need to check whether there at least one store in all lists. In the first row store 7 is in all lists

Comment: your question is absolutely unclear. For starters what are stores and products is undefined, please be explicit. In `[[67, 124], [30, 35, 38]]` there are no common numbers. What is the sense of "*there are two stores in which we can find these products: 67 and 35*"? And what are "*these products*"?

Comment: I wrote an answer but there are many open ended question here :

1. Are we only checking specifically if we have 2 instances
2. Some example is needed to make this understandable. Specially the the last para of explanation as there are no common elements in row 2 and row 3 so both should be 0

Comment: I've changed the problem description.

Comment: @Alice thanks but it's still unclear. "*check whether all of these lists contain the same value*" -> in the first row not all values are common. Did you mean "*at least one value*"?

Comment: @mozway  Yes, I do need to check for at least one common value in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check whether there is at least one item in common in all sublists per row, you can compute a set intersection and check if it's not empty:

```
df['flag'] = [1 if set.intersection(*map(set, l)) else 0 for l in df['Store']]
```

Or, if you need a more complex function that can also use the other columns (note that this is less efficient):

```
def same_store(row):
    if len(set.intersection(*map(set, row['Store']))) > 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
    
df['flag'] = df.apply(same_store, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                          Store  Items  flag
0  [[7], [7], [7, 14], [7, 14]]      1     1
1     [[67, 124], [30, 35, 38]]      2     0
2       [[92, 147], [86], [53]]      1     0
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Store': [[[7], [7], [7, 14], [7, 14]],
                             [[67, 124], [30, 35, 38]],
                             [[92, 147], [86], [53]]],
                   'Items': [1, 2, 1],
                   })
```

Comment: I've already tried something simmilar and I get 'TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable' with this function

Comment: @Alice this means you have something other than lists of lists in your column. Maybe NaNs? What is the output of `df['Store'].isna().any()`?

Comment: Oh, I have found a mistake at another place of my code. Your function did work, thanks a lot!